# distribution of population in genetic algorithms

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm

My questions is ,if there are  genetic optimization algorithms where the population keeps i.i.d (independ identically distributed) during all iterations. The most common ones like NSGA2 or SPEA2 mix the current population with the previous one so that mixed population is no longer iid. But are there algorithms where the distribution of the population changes during optimization but still remains i.i.d?

Comment: Why do you want it to be identically distributed doesn't this kinda kills the idea of the algorithm ? The only possible reason I see is to escape a local maximum

Comment: @Wald you are very right. The thing is, I found a very fast algorithm to find approximate pareto-ranks. That algorithm needs as input a set of iid data, but sometimes seems to work for non iid data too (I dont know why). My idea was to apply that algorithm in NSGA2 but the results are far from correct. Thats why I was looking for some modifications for NSGA2 where I could apply the fast algorithm but with no success. Btw do you know some applications where the knowledge of approximate pareto ranks could be useful?

Comment: to be honest i'm no really familiar with pareto methods, but after a brief look up it seem they can be useful if you are doing a large scale genetic generations. For example if you have one genetic algorithm setting up the static data for another inner genetic algorithm as they would take quite a while and narrowing the useful genes for the outer algorithm would be useful. But on the other hand i'm pretty sure that the pareto ranks wouldn't be really accurate when your data isn't identically distributed.

Comment: @Wald thx for your effort. I think  that the solutions in a population are too strongly correlated to each other, for an algorithm thats needs i.i.d samples to work. Well there are applications like anomaly detection where the percentage of elements which are dependent from each other is quite low. The algorihtm seems to work there, but there is no mathematical proof

Answer (score 0):

You can try fitness uniform selection https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0103015. 
But,  IMHO the results won't be very good.

Comment: thnx for the link. I forgot to mention that I am looking for multiobjective optimization algorithms. The paper just covers single objectives do you know if there is a generalization?

Comment: You can make it multiobjective by changing the fitness function.